# Different layouts in the same activity

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, passwords

Sorry for my english. I'm working on an Android app which in it first activity has a password textfield. Depending on the password, the app goes to an especific activity. 
My problem its i have several activities to open, but I think its more effective have only one activity and several layouts,then, depending of the password, the app opens the same activity but whith different layout whith information. But I have no idea how to do that.

My code its:

```
package com.example.museoprueba;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class interfazSq extends Activity {

    private EditText hola;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.interfazsq);
        hola=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.hola);
    }

    public void lAcuriosidades(View v) {



        String clave=hola.getText().toString();


        if (clave.equals("cebra")) {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,sqCebra.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else if (clave.equals("jaguar")){
            Intent i=new Intent(this,sqJaguar.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Well you could pass the password as a string extra start the generic activity, once inside get the password and choose which view to use there.

Comment: Thanks, but how i get a password in other activity?

Comment: `(String)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(theNameYouGaveIt);`

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent.setExtra to pass your configuration data into the activity.  Then use getIntent in your called activity to adjust your display.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Fragment** to dynamically change different layouts in single Activity:

1. Extends **FragmentActivity** instead of Activity.
2. In your Activity's layout (interfazsq.xml), add one of **any layout** such as LinearLayout, RelativeLyaout...etc
3. In your interfazSq class, inflate that layout as a **ViewGroup**.
4. Use **FragmentManager** to dynamically add Fragment into that ViewGroup. You don't have to use Intent or leave current Activity for displaying different layouts for different password conditions.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding